# Two bar charts in matplotlib overlapping the wrong way

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, overlapping

I'm creating a bar plot with matplotlib in Python, and I'm having a bit of a problem with the overlapping bars:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = range(1,10)
b = range(4,13)
ind = np.arange(len(a))
width = 0.65

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.bar(ind+width, a, width, color='#b0c4de')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.bar(ind+width+0.35, b, 0.45, color='#deb0b0')

ax.set_xticks(ind+width+(width/2))
ax.set_xticklabels(a)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Barplot]

I want the blue bars to be in front, not the red ones. The only way I have managed to do so so far was to switch ax and ax2, but then the ylabels are going to be reversed as well, which I don't want. Isn't there a simple way to tell matplotlib to render ax2 before ax?

In addition, the ylabels on the right are being cut off by plt.tight_layout(). Is there a way to avoid this while still using tight_layout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps there is a better way that I do not know about; however, you *can* swap `ax` and `ax2` and also swap the location of the corresponding `y`-ticks with

```
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position("left")
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = range(1,10)
b = range(4,13)
ind = np.arange(len(a))
width = 0.65

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(ind+width+0.35, b, 0.45, color='#deb0b0')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.bar(ind+width, a, width, color='#b0c4de')

ax.set_xticks(ind+width+(width/2))
ax.set_xticklabels(a)

ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position("left")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

By the way, instead of doing the math yourself, you can center the bars using the `align='center'` parameter:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = range(1,10)
b = range(4,13)
ind = np.arange(len(a))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(ind+0.25, b, 0.45, color='#deb0b0', align='center')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.bar(ind, a, 0.65, color='#b0c4de', align='center')

plt.xticks(ind, a)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position("left")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

(The result is essentially the same as the above.)

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.
And thanks for the tip, too! I always thought there just had to be a simpler way to do it..